# Tratamento de retornos diferentes de JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, api

Estou trabalhando numa integração via API com JSON.
Não cheguei a implementar nada ainda em meu código C#, estou por enquanto estudando a API mas já me surgiu uma dúvida.

Tenho um método de Login que se tiver sucesso me retorna um tipo de resposta, e se tiver falha me retorna um tipo totalmente diferente.

Exemplo:

Se tiver sucesso o retorno é :

```
{
   "Autenticacao": {
          "tokenAutenticacao": "9f6530dad90c7f8eda5670"
          "idUsuario": "c7f8eda5670"
    }
}
```

Usando [json2charp](http://json2csharp.com/) crio a seguinte classe:

```
public class Autenticacao
{
    public string tokenAutenticacao { get; set; }
    public string idUsuario { get; set; }
}

public class LoginSucesso
{
    public Autenticacao Autenticacao { get; set; }
}
```

E se falhar o login, o retorno é:

```
{
  "status": {
    "code": 403,
    "name": "Forbidden"
  },
"mensagem": "Login falhou",
"exception": "Blah Blah blah",
"dataHora": "18/06/2015 10:47:47"
}
```

Convertendo para uma classe C# tenho:

```
public class Status
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class LoginFalha
{
    public Status status { get; set; }
    public string mensagem { get; set; }
    public string exception { get; set; }
    public string dataHora { get; set; }
}
```

Obs.: Troquei RootObject por LoginSucesso e LoginFalha.

Pretendo usar o [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) para deserializar o objeto JSON, fazendo algo assim:

```
LoginSucesso resultadoJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginSucesso>(meuJson);
```

Mas e se o login falhar?

Como devo tratar no código C#?

Trato uma exception e tento `LoginFalha resultadoJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginFalha>(meuJson);` ????

Answer (score 1):

Pode tratar a excepção mas será mais elegante utilizar o classe [JsonSchema](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm) para fazer a validação.

Comece por declarar uma string com o *Schema*

```
string schemaJson = @"{
   'description': 'Autenticaçao',
   'type': 'object',
   'properties':
   {
     'tokenAutenticacao': {'type':'string'},
     'idUsuario': {'type':'string'}
  }
}";
```

Crie um objecto *JsonSchema* passando o *schema* ao construtor:

```
JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson);
```

Crie um *JObject* a partir do seu *json*

```
JObject autenticacao = JObject.Parse(resultadoJson);
```

Faça a validação:

```
bool valido = autenticacao.IsValid(schema);
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes primeiro converter para `JObject` e depois verificar se tem uma key `exception` antes de converter

```
var obj = JObject.parse(meuJson);

if(obj["exception"] != null)
{
    var falha = obj.ToObject<LoginFalha>();
}
else
{
    var sucesso = obj.ToObject<LoginSucesso>();
}
```

Mas devias validar com um JSchema, como indicado pelo @ramaral - é uma solução mais robusta.